# Prove that $na_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n \}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers. Prove that if the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \sin (nx)$$

converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$ then $na_n \rightarrow 0$.

I find difficulty to prove this. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \sin (nx)$ imply convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$?

Comment: Use the uniform convergence of the series. Since the series is uniformly convergent so for a given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge N$ we have $|\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} a_k \sin (kx)| < \epsilon$. Now take $x=\frac {1} {2n}$ and observe that $\sin (\frac {1} {2}) \le \sin (kx) \le \sin 1$. Then you will have $\epsilon > |\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} a_k \sin (kx)| = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} a_k \sin (kx) \ge \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} a_{2n} \sin (\frac {1} {2}) = 2na_{2n} ({\frac {1} {2}} \sin(\frac {1} {2}))$ $\implies$ $2na_{2n} \rightarrow 0$. Similarly you can prove for the odd terms.ok!

Comment: very nice answer!